# Можно ли использовать Bootstrap 4 в Bitrix (управление сайтом)

Tags: bootstrap

Возникла необходимость создать сайт на Bitrix, раньше никогда с ним не сталкивался. В руководстве написано "*Не рекомендуется подключать Bootstrap v 4, так как эта версия не имеет обратной совместимости.*"

На мой вопрос, что это означает, получил ответ от службы поддержки "*Шаблоны наших стандартных компонентов используют Bootstrap версии 3. Если вы подключите версию 4, могут возникнуть проблемы.*"

Я так и не понял, как с Bootstrap 4 могут или не могут возникнуть проблемы? Стоит ли прислушаться к совету службы поддержки?

Comment: Не хотите проблем - не используйте. Умеете решать проблемы - делайте, в битриксе можно переопределить шаблоны почти всего. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/

Comment: Многие классы BS3 были изменены или вообще удалены в BS4, так что просто подключить четверку вместо тройки не получится - в верстке остаются старые бесполезные классы, которые надо будет править руками.

Answer (score 2):

В последних версия битрикса bootstrap 4 появился в расширения. Подключить можно так:

`use Bitrix\Main\UI\Extension;
Extension::load('ui.bootstrap4');`

Расширения хранятся в папке /bitrix/js/ui/ там должна быть папка bootstrap4. Если ее нет, то расширение не подключится.

Comment: Как сделать чтобы подключался `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` вместо `bootstrap.min.js`?